# how will JavaScript's for loop behave without curly brackets? need a help to understand the following code

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var arr=[5,7,2,6,3]
for(var c=1; c<=5;c+=2)
var x=arr[3]                    
x=(x%4)                        
x*=2                           
c=(c%x)                        
console.log(arr[c])
```

could you explain how the code executes with a clear explanation? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Only the first statement after that `for` loop is considered to be in its loop body without curly braces.

Comment: i couldn't understand how the c gets it values from the loop

Comment: `c` is declared in the loop initialization. If you use `let` instead of `var`, then `c` will be bound to its loop body only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work same as

```
var arr = [5,7,2,6,3];

for(var c=1; c<=5; c+=2) {
    var x=arr[3] //this will always assign arr[3] which is 6 to x
}
when this loop finish with c = 7 and x = 6;
x = 7%4
x = 1;
x = x*2
x = 1*2 = 2
then,
c = 7 % 2 = 3;
arr[3] = 6:
console.log(arr[3]) //result 6
```

Answer (score 0):

var arr=[5,7,2,6,3]

fill the variable "arr" with an array, filled with 5 integers

```
for(var c=1; c<=5;c+=2)
```

marks the start of a for loop. for: var c=1, while c is lower or equal to 5, run the bracketed code and increment c by 2

```
var x=arr[3]
```

variable "x" is the 4th element in the array (note that 0 counts as index, so 3 is (0,1,2,3) the 4th element)

```
x=(x%4)
```

refer to [this explenation of the modulo operation](https://www.quora.com/In-which-cases-is-the-Modulo-operation-used-in-programming)

```
x*=2
```

x is equal to itself times 2

```
c=(c%x)
```

c is equal to c modulo x

```
console.log(arr[c])
```

log to console, the c-th element in the array "arr"

Comment: the logged answer is 6. means the value of c is 3. final value of x at `x*=2` is 4. so at `c=c%x` it says c must be 7 before modulo operation. i mean `c=7%4`. my point how c got the value 7?

Comment: after failing the last condition  `7 <= 5` c get it value 7 right?